# what is the best way to develop a lightweight distributed system using Ruby and mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, distributed

what is the best way to develop a lightweight distributed system using Ruby and mongodb ?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without more details about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoMatic](http://mongomatic.com/) is a lightweight implementation, worth checking out.

[LightMongo](https://github.com/elliotcm/light_mongo) is also a very light weight implementation, but unfortunately it hasn't been touched for over half a year, which is a bad sign.

Otherwise, using the Ruby driver of mongo itself isn't that difficult either.